# Run each protractor test file separately in Webstorm

Tags: javascript, ide, webstorm

Protractor can be run and debug from Webstorm by adding a new configurations, but that will run all the spec.js files that matches the file pattern. I want to run a single test file without changing the name.

I want to select a protractor test file in webstorm, right click > run and it would run. Is it possible to do something like that ? Like a custom run action?
Right now, if I click run, it runs by mocha.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that.

- Just go to debug drop down
- choose "edit configurations"
- click the plus icon
- choose Node.js
- Then enter the following:

Node interpreter: /usr/bin/node
Working directory: where your files are
Javascript file: [where protractor cli.js is]
Application parameters: tests/conf.js --specs [path-to-spec]

You can see in the image that I have created an entry for each one of my tests, that way I can run each test individually

I hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But with this, I will have to edit the filename in the parameter everytime when I am going to run a different spec file. I am looking for a technique where I can right click on a file, click Run and it would run directly by adding its name with '--specs' params.  Right now, the workaround I found is the 'External Tool' option in Webstorm, where I can define params using macros.

Comment: Can you post your solution? It sounds great!

Comment: +1 for your solution @user6083264, can you post it?